# param is missing or the value is empty: room

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-7

i created an edit page to edit the room(model) and update the form to change the current name and current capacity to whatever we wish but i am getting an error

`ActionController::ParameterMissing in RoomsController#edit`

`param is missing or the value is empty: room`

> rooms_controller.rb

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_room, only: %i[show edit update]


    def index
        @rooms = Room.all
    end

    def show
    end
    
    def new
        @room = Room.new
    end

    def create
        @room = Room.new(room_params)   
        respond_to do |format|
            if @room.save
                format.html { redirect_to room_url(@room), notice: "Room was created Successfully" }

            else
                format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end 
        end
    end

    def edit
        respond_to do |format|
            if @room.update(room_params)
                format.html { redirect_to room_url(@room), notice: "Room was successfully updated!" }

            else
                format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end

    end
    

    private
        def set_room
            @room = Room.find(params[:id])
        end

        def room_params
            params.require(:room).permit(:name, :capacity)    
        end

        
end
```

> edit.hml.erb

```
<h2>Edit Room</h2>

<%= render "form", room: @room %>
```

> _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: room) do |form| %>


    <% if room.errors.any? %>
        <div style="color: red">
            <h2><%= pluralize(room.errors.count, "errors") %> Prohibited this Room from saving</h2>
        

        <ul>
            <% room.errors.each do |error| %>
                <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
        </div>

    <% end %>

    <div>
    <%= form.label :name, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div>
    <%= form.label :capacity, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.number_field :capacity %>
    </div>

    <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

i am using the same partial `_form.html.erb` for both `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb` , is it because of using same partial form for edit and new or there is some other reason?

> new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Room</h1>

<%= render "form", room: @room %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong action.

In [Rails flavored REST](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) the `edit` action responds to a `GET /rooms/:id/edit` request and just renders the form. It should also be idempotent. There is no `room` parameter since you're not responding to a form submission.

Updating the resource is done in the `update` method (`PATCH /rooms/:id`).

```erb
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  
  # you can actually completely omit this method 
  # Rails will implicitly render edit.html.erb anyways
  # GET /rooms/1/edit
  def edit
  end
  
  # PATCH /rooms/1
  def update
    # you don't need to use MimeResponds if you're only responding to HTML requests. KISS
    if @room.update(room_params)
      redirect_to @room, notice: "Room was successfully updated!"         
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: oh damn, i  made a silly mistake xD , my bad i forgot to notice that i did it in edit method xD
Anyways thanks for the info! :D